# How to zoom canvas by two fingers and move?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I can draw by fingers in canvas, but I can not zoom it by two fingers without loss of scale drawn

and I want to do infinite my canvas size

I have this code:

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawingView dv ;
private Paint mPaint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dv = new DrawingView(this);
    setContentView(dv);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
}

public class DrawingView extends View {

    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Path circlePath;

    public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();



        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}


}
```

Please give me advice how to do it?

And I also want to do infinite my canvas size - its optional.
Main problem is zoom

Answer (score 0):

My advice - you can use opengl. It's looks like you want to create some drawer, but canvas not perfect solution for this. Currently almost all devices support opengl es. It faster than canvas and you can made many another function(as scaling, image pasting, 3d objects etc.) much more easier. [Here](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/) you can find a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Yoo should use `ScaleGestureDetector` to scale your canvas. This is my sample code:

```
     private class MyScaleGestureListener implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener { 
           public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
              scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor(); 
              return true;
        }
           public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) { 
              Log.d("myZoomTag", "SCALE STARTED"); 
              return true; 
        }
           public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) { 
             Log.d("myZoomTag", "SCALE ENDED"); 
        } 

  }
```

Here `scaleFactor`  is global variable. In your `onDraw` method you should do something like this:

```
bitmapWidth *= scaleFactor;
bitmapHeight *= scaleFactor;
```